# after switching flutter channel to beta , started getting error Type 'SystemMouseCursor' not found

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-channel

t[image: this is the error what i am getting] i don't know which flutter channel i was previously working for that it was working fine.when i  was trying to create web app for that i switch flutter channel to beta after switching that channel when i reopen my old project i am start getting this error.
i am using android studio in ubuntu can anybody help me here? i tried to switch every channel it is not getting resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

library was outdated i update syncFusion_flutter_pdfViewer